# Is it possible to add facebook icons on the blog page of a Shopify site, inside of the blog loop?

Tags: facebook, icons, blogs, shopify, liquid

I want a user to be able to like an individual article on the blog page of a Shopify site.  I have added my social media icons inside of the blog loop.

**blog.liquid**

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}<!-- START ENTRY {{ forloop.index }} -->
<div id="post{{ article.id }}">

{{ article.content | strip_html | truncate: 40 }} <br/> <a href="{{ article.url}}">Read More</a>

{% assign description = article.title | escape | replace:' ','%20' %}
{% assign link = article.url %}
{% include 'social' %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**social.liquid Snippet**

```
<div class="social-plugins">

<span class="twitter">
<a href="http://twitter.com/share"{% if template == 'product' or template == 'article' or template == 'blog' %} data-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ link }}"{% endif %} data-text="{% if template == 'product' %}{{ product.title | escape }} by {{ product.vendor | escape }}{% elsif template == 'blog' %}{{ social.title | escape }}{% else %}{{ page_title | escape }}{% endif %}" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="bondiNYC">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</span>

<span class="facebook">
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={{shop.url}}{{link}}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"</iframe>
</span>

<span class="pinterest">
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={{ shop.url }}{{ link }}&description={{ description }}&media={{src | escape}}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
</span>

</div>
```

The like button works if I just put in {{shop.url}}{{blog.url}} but not when I add {{shop.url}}{{link}}. {{link}} is assigned based on the page.

Answer (score 1):

In my shop - I do this by using:

```
{{ shop.url }}{{ article.url }}
```

That will return the article's URL to be inserted in the facebook/twitter/pinterest iframe.

Note: Be sure to check that the code is being rendered on the `blog.liquid` page. I do this in my equivalent `social.liquid`